# I am getting : There was an error in the forked process in selenium webdriver project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

Trying to run TestNG.xml which is present under different project through Maven -> Run As -> Maven Test. Is it correct or is there any other way to do this type of configuration.

**Below is the error log**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project MavenSetup: There are test failures.

[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: keywardDrivenFramework.ExecuteTestCase

[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process

[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: keywardDrivenFramework.ExecuteTestCase
```

**Project Structure**

Project 1 - Maven Setup and dependencies

Project 2 - `testng.xml` (Which i need to run)

Comment: .class file is not generated, So first you need to compile the code and it will generate .class file as interpreter.

Comment: Issue got resolved after generating .class file. Thanks for your help.